# How to pass the empty interface

Tags: go, sqlx

I have a sqlx query function with interface as passing parameter, now i want to using the raw query string, how to omit this interface parameter?

```
func QuerySlice(query string, data interface{}) error {
    q := queryString(query, data)
}

// If pass the data
data := struct {
    id string `db:"id"`
}{
    Id: id,
}
QuerySlice(query, data)

// The query sql is
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
WHERE
    id = :id

// Now i want the raw sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
WHERE
    id = 'XXX'

// How to pass the data interface to omit this parameter
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `NamedExec`, you could pass a empty map to sqlx

```golang
QuerySlice(rawQuery, map[string]interface{}{})
```